# How to find a discord.js user's permissions from a message mention?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js, typeerror

I'm making a ban command and I need to check if the target user has administrator permissions. I've tried:

```js
const user = message.mentions.users.first();
const userMember = message.guild.members.fetch(user)
```

But I'm getting an error: `TypeError: userMember.hasPermission is not a function`

Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.fetch()` returns a promise so you need to `await` the results:

```js
const userMember = await message.guild.members.fetch(user)
userMember.hasPermission()
```

You could also get the member instead of the user from the [`mentions`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageMentions?scrollTo=members):

```js
const member = message.mentions.members.first()
member.hasPermission()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `userMember.permissions.has`. According to the Discord.JS docs (https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=permissions) you need to do it like that. It seems like it has been changed in v12.

---

EDIT: please take a look at Zsolt's answer, you will also have to `await` the `.fetch`, otherwise it will not work.

```js
const user = message.mentions.users.first();
const userMember = await message.guild.members.fetch(user)
```

Comment: On the same page you can see the `hasPermission()` method too: https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=hasPermission